# Place jboss-ejb-client.properties file on your classpath but how to Client Classpath?

Tags: classpath, jboss7.x

Jboss7.1 final, how to find client classpath or the location where jboss-ejb-client.properties file should go?

Answer (score 0):

If you run app from terminal, then:

1. Folder from witch app is executed
2. If app is packaged as jar, root of jar, or add Class-Path entry in MANIFEST.MF that points to folder with file
3. JRE lib/ext folder (not recomended)
4. run java with -cp argument

Comment: I have more specifically looking for Maven, JBoss7.1 application server class-path. 
Let me give you long story. I have to place jboss-ejb-client.properties to call the EJB3 deployed locally on JBoss7.1 server but I am not able to locate client classpath location. 
Is it where server is sitting (C:\core-dev\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final) or the Meta-INF of web apps?

Comment: if you use maven, src/main/resources is proper folder, as file located there will be copied to classes root directory. Don't even bother in putting properties to any server folder, as jboss7 has modular class loader, which will not grab anything what is not defined as module.